# ¿Es posible hacer hotreload al navegador al aplicar un cambio a un archivo .html? usando Python3 - Flask

Tags: html5, python-3.x, flask, chrome

¡Hola gente! estoy empezando en el desarrollo web con Python3 y flask. me preguntaba si existe la posibilidad de que al aplicar un cambio al archivo html, no haga falta recargar el navegador. similar al desarrollo en Flutter; porque solo con F5 no se aplican, tengo que hacer: **Ctrl**+**Shift**+**R** y es como que un poco tedioso.

Encontré un ejemplo en la versión en inglés del foro en donde se utiliza un paquete de python llamado Livereload, quedó así en mi **index.py**:

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
 from liverealod import Server #parte del ejemplo para livereload

 app = Flask(__name__)
 @app.route('/', methods['GET','POST'])
 def index():
     return render_template("index.html")


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
     server = Server(app.wsgi_app) #parte del ejemplo para livereload
     server.serve() #parte del ejemplo para livereload
```

Está modificado ligeramente en comparación al ejemplo que encontré pero no me funciona, guardo cambios en .html pero el navegador Chrome no aplica cambios.

Comment: Sospecho que el livereload ocurre si modificas el script flask, no ante cambios en los templates, aunque igual se puede configurar a través de `server.watch()` (https://livereload.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#server-watch)

Comment: efectivamente joven, probé `server.watch()` y era lo que andaba buscando. lo que más me gusta es que se puede aplicar a varios archivos. lo apliqué al .html y .css. en cuando guardo aplica los cambios.